# Angularjs $routeProvider resolve returning unknown provider

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I am trying to authenticate a user's login and prevent them from accessing certain routes when they are not logged in. I have the following code:

```
var isUserLoggedIn = function($q, $timeout, $http, $Location, $rootScope) {
  // Initialize a new promise.
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  // Check is user is logged in
  $http.get('/isLoggedIn').success(function(user) {
    if(user !== '0') {  // User is logged in
      deferred.resolve();
    } else {  // Use is not logged in
      $rootScope.message = 'You need to log in.';
      deferred.reject();
      $location.url('/login');
    }
  });

  return deferred.promise;
};

$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/index',
    controller: 'IndexCtrl'
  })
  .when('/registerUser', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/registerUser',
    controller: 'RegisterUserCtrl'
  })
  .when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/login',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  })
  .when('/userProfile', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/userProfile',
    controller: 'UserProfileCtrl',
    resolve: {
      loggedin: isUserLoggedIn
    }
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
```

For the controller I have the following:

```
angular.module('enigmaApp.controllers', [])
.controller('UserProfileCtrl', ['$scope', 'loggedin', function($scope, loggedin) {
    $scope.name = "john doe";
    $scope.loggedin = loggedin;
}]);
```

However I get the following error when I try to access the /userProfile route.

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $LocationProvider <- $Location <- loggedin

After searching through a bunch of answers on here it seems the issue for most people was using ng-controller in their views, however I am not using that. My jade views are below:

Layout.jade

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
html(ng-app="enigmaApp", lang="en")
    head
        meta(charset='utf8')
        meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no')
        base(href='/')
        title Enigma base platform
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/app.css')
        link(rel="stylesheet", href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css')
    body
        div.content-wrapper
            block body
```

index.jade

```
extends layout

block body
  div.user.f-right(ng-controller='NavCtrl')
    a(href="/") Home
    |  | 
    a(href='/login') Login
    |  | 
    a(href='registerUser') Register
    |  | 
    a(href='/logout', target='_self') Logout
    |  | 
    a(href='/userProfile') User Profile
  h1 Enigma Health

  div(ng-view)
```

userProfile.jade

```
h3 Welcome {{name}}!
```

Comment: Did you try changing `$Location` to `$location`?

Comment: Good eye! That was the problem. hours wasted over a capitol letter *sigh*

Comment: I'll add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, changing `$Location` to `$location` fixed the issue.